# Hide icons from big screens

Tags: html, css

I want to create a website and with this website I want it to be compatible with all small, large and medium screens

And I want to put two icons on the small screens and hide them from the big screens, and for that I put this instruction in the CSS file:

```
nav .fa{
    display: none !important;
}
```

But the icons are not hidden from the big screens.

How can I solve the problem?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>
        University Website Design
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome- 
 free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<section class="header">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/TP-Link-Logo.wine.svg">
        </a>

        <div class="nav-links">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        HOME
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        ABOUT
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        COURSE
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        BLOG
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        CONTACT
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </nav>

    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>
            World's Biggest University
        </h1>

        <p>
            Make Website is now one of the easiest thing in the world.
            you just need to learn HTML,CSS , <br> Javascript and you are good to go.
        </p>

        <a class="hero-btn">
            Visit Us to Know More
        </a>
    </div>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS code through which I design the interface with the sidebar, and I want the icon to appear only in the small interfaces.

style.css:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7) , rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), 
    url("images/b.png");
    /*background-size: 100%; This line will make the background responsive*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;

    /*padding: 20em;*/
    /*background-image: url("images/b.png");*/
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    /*background-size: 100%;*/
    /*background-position: center center;*/
    /*background-position: 0 0; This statement like center value*/
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    /*padding: 1-top bottom  2-right left*/
    padding: 1% 4%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav img{
    width: 150px;
}

.nav-links{
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}

.nav-links ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.813rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.nav-links ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #4accd5;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}


.text-box{
    color: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.text-box h1{
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.text-box p{
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
}

.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    background: #f44336;
    transition: 1s;

}


nav .fa{
    display: none !important;
}



@media(max-width: 700px) {

    .text-box h1{
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }

    .nav-links ul li{
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        background: #f44336;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    /*nav .fa{*/
    /*    display: block;*/
    /*    color: white;*/
    /*    margin: 10px;*/
    /*    font-size: 22px;*/
    /*    cursor: pointer;*/
    /*}*/

}
```

Comment: Use media queries. Ref - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: have you tried using `i` instead `fa`?

Answer (score 1):

Use Media query in css to identify the screen size, when the screen size is more than your screen size hide it.

```css
.div1{
  color: red;
}
.div2{
  visibility: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div2 {
visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" >Iam always visible in red color</div>
<div class="div2" >Iam Only Visible when the screen width is below 600px</div>
```

**Note**
You can also use `display:none` property

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>
        University Website Design
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"/>
    <style>
    .header{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7) , rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), 
    url("images/b.png");
    /*background-size: 100%; This line will make the background responsive*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;

    /*padding: 20em;*/
    /*background-image: url("images/b.png");*/
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    /*background-size: 100%;*/
    /*background-position: center center;*/
    /*background-position: 0 0; This statement like center value*/
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    /*padding: 1-top bottom  2-right left*/
    padding: 1% 4%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav img{
    width: 150px;
}

.nav-links{
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}

.nav-links ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.813rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.nav-links ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #4accd5;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}


.text-box{
    color: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.text-box h1{
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.text-box p{
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
}

.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    background: #f44336;
    transition: 1s;

}




@media(min-width: 768px) {
nav .fa{
    display: none;
}
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {

    .text-box h1{
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }

    .nav-links ul li{
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        background: #f44336;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    nav .fa{
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    }
    /*nav .fa{*/
    /*    display: block;*/
    /*    color: white;*/
    /*    margin: 10px;*/
    /*    font-size: 22px;*/
    /*    cursor: pointer;*/
    /*}*/

}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<section class="header">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/TP-Link-Logo.wine.svg">
        </a>

        <div class="nav-links">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        HOME
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        ABOUT
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        COURSE
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        BLOG
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        CONTACT
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </nav>

    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>
            World's Biggest University
        </h1>

        <p>
            Make Website is now one of the easiest thing in the world.
            you just need to learn HTML,CSS , <br> Javascript and you are good to go.
        </p>

        <a class="hero-btn">
            Visit Us to Know More
        </a>
    </div>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Please  change CDN and replace code and check if you got good result without important applied.